# Change color of one word in attributed textview (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

I have a textview with an Attributed text.  I am trying to change the color of the first 14 letters ("Privacy Policy") of the attributed text to a stored value, "appTintColor".  This app tint color is stored in the p list and has a different color for each app target.

How do I change the first 5 letters of the textView's attributed text to this variable "appTintColor"?  I know I can change the color to an RGB/HEX color easily using the xCode interface... But I want to change this color to the variable "appTintColor" which is dynamic based on the app target.

Do I add an outlet to the textfield, subscript the first 14 characters, and set it to appTintColor?  That is the logic I have but I can't seem to get it in code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `NSMutableAttributedString` - try the following code:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor greenColor];

NSString *privacyPolicyFullStr = @"Privacy policy\n blah stuff things blah cat bat mongoose platypus";

NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:privacyPolicyFullStr attributes:nil];

NSString *privacyPolicyShortStr = @"Privacy Policy"; //just to avoid using a magic number
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color};
[mutAttrStr setAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, privacyPolicyShortStr.length)];

self.textView.attributedText = mutAttrStr;
```

Comment: In case there would be other attributes (like paragraph styles, bold, etc.) set through InterfaceBuilder, `NSMutableAttributedString  *mutAttrStr = [self.textView.attributedText mutableCopy];` could be better. And maybe call `addAttributes:range:` instead of `setAttributes:range:` for the same reason.